# How to retrieve unspent outputs on mSigna

Tags: synchronization, output, msigna

Due to an upgrade, I had to recreate my wallet (vault) file from scratch - a process that took over a week. During this time, I was able to spend one coin (sending it to blockchain.info) because I somehow managed to find an old copy of the software and it worked for one transaction only and then fell over. That appeared to work fine. When looking at the 'watch only' address imported into my blockchain.info wallet, it showed the spend plus the remainder at that address being sent to another address starting with '3'. I was comfortable with this because mSigna wallet addresses start with '3' because they can be multi-sig wallets. However, when mSigna finally completed syncing my new vault file, the unspent coin actually shows up in my list of wallet transactions as 'spent'. Obviously this is a shock to the system - it's quite a bit of coin.

However, I think what happened is that the address of the unspent output is somehow not in sync with my wallet and that's why I'm showing a balance below that which I should truly have.

I can think of two possible paths forward:

1. If I can get the private key from mSigna, I can move the funds manually through a site like blockchain.info, or
2. I try to re-sync the entire wallet again - and wait a week or more

Are there any other ideas worth considering? Thanks in advance for your help.

Jim

Answer (score 2):

Can you please send the sharedacct file to support@ciphrex.com? Thank you!

[image: CiphrexLogo]

Comment: It looks like a comment, but it's not, and don't downvote this: The one who submitted this answer is working at the company who made mSigna, so it's valid answer.

Comment: Hi Eric. Yes. I can send it. I'll put your name in the subject line so you can pick it out more easily. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was unable to sync properly or send transaction from mSigma.  Transaction failed to confirm in mSigna despite having thousands of confirmations on the blockchain.  Every time I would try to send a transaction mSigna would crash.  I spent 3 weeks upgrading schemas, rebuilding vaults, and syncing transactions.  Version 0.10.6 specifically stated that it would fix the situation yet still failed.

After 3 weeks of dealing with mSigna's bugs I tried to get the private keys out so I could sweep the keys.  It's extremely difficult to get the private keys for each address without knowing the derivation path.  In the end I generated a transaction with mSigna and had to broadcast it to the blockchain manually.  This method worked perfectly for me and I safely got all my bitcoins and Bitcoin Cash out of my corrupted mSigna wallet.

I highly suggest finding a new wallet option ASAP and NEVER use mSigna again.  ***mSigna is unstable, poorly supported, bug-ridden, and a danger to your Bitcoins!***

1. Create backup of vault file
2. Disconnect from node/localhost
3. Determine appropriate fee to ensure transaction is approved by blockchain. 
   Example site:  https://estimatefee.com/
4. Create 'Send' transaction using different wallet address
5. Enable 'Coin Control' option and select coin
6. Send full amount of specified coin **minus the fee**, make sure 0 funds remain to prevent bitcoin being sent to 'Change Address'
7. Sign transaction
8. Export 'Raw' transaction to clipboard
9. Broadcast 'Raw' transaction to blockchain with online tool or node CLI. Example site:  https://blockchain.info/pushtx
10. Monitor new wallet for transaction to be confirmed
11. Repeat with all coins
12. Once all transactions are confirmed destroy your mSigna vaults and don't ever use mSigna again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the previous to 10.6 code that sends the change to a change address created by someone else. A lot of us have lost coins this way.

Do you know how to do the above in order to spend Bitcoin Gold coins that are on their blockchain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that was really a 'bug'.  There was a huge push to get everyone 10.6 after a flaw was found in 10.2 that would cause 'coin loss'.  Things are getting really shady around msigna now.  Be safe and transfer your coins to another wallet using the method listed above.  *Also, be sure to use transactions that won't generate a change address.*

I used the 'sign & broadcast raw' trick for Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash, not sure if it will work with Bitcoin Gold.  I believe Ciphrex will need to release version that is compatible with Bitcoin Gold.